# Iterate through dictionary key/value pairs where the value is an array

Tags: c#

I am trying to display the elements of a key/value pair from a dictionary where the value is an array. It is a dictionary of usernames where the key is a string representing the name of the user and the values are the users attributes. I want each key/value pair to be listed together, so the output would be like this:

> User1 (Key)
>   User1_email
>   user1_fullName
>   User1_displayName
>
> User2 (Key)
>   User2_email
>   user2_fullName
>   User2_displayName
>   etc...

However, the result I am getting is that it is displaying the correct key but only the last elements of the value are being displayed. For example, here is the output I am getting:

> User1 (Key)
>   User2_email
>   user2_fullName
>   User2_displayName
>
> User2 (Key)
>   User2_email
>   user2_fullName
>   User2_displayName
>   etc...

Here is my foreach loop:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string[]> entry in userNames)
{
    txtOutput.Text += entry.Key;
    foreach (string value in entry.Value)
    {
        txtOutput.Text += value + Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
```

The nested foreach loop seems to be iterating over ALL of the values regardless of the key, but I only want it to iterate over the values associated with the CURRENT key in the parent foreach loop. Hope my question makes sense, any help is appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: Take it one step at a time. What happens if you remove the inner loop and just keep the outer one? What is the output from that?

Comment: @Daniel, why not?

Comment: @demo read the issue incorrectly

Comment: I don't see any problem with the loop. I would like to see how you're populating the dictionary to be sure that the string arrays going into each key are correct.

Comment: @Romen
Here is the code adding to Dictionary
```
string[] tempArray = new string[5];
                for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
                    {
                        if (j != 0)
                            tempArray[j-1] = userInfo[i, j];
                    }
                    userNames.Add(userInfo[i, 0], tempArray);
                }
```
I have a 2 dimensional array that I am iterating and make the first element the key and the remaining elements the value. I used a breakpoint at dict add to verify

Comment: It looks like you are declaring ```string[] tempArray``` outside the for loops, which means each iteration modifies the same array instance. Dictionaries store references to the array you add to each key, not a copy of the array, so in this for-loop you are modifying the arrays associated with the previous keys. I think I will post this as an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You gave the following code in a comment for populating your dictionary:

```csharp
string[] tempArray = new string[5];

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
        if (j != 0) tempArray[j-1] = userInfo[i, j];
    }
    userNames.Add(userInfo[i, 0], tempArray);
}
```

It looks like you were hoping to reduce memory usage by using a single array outside the for loop. However, this has an unexpected side-effect on your dictionary!

Dictionaries will store arrays by reference. On the first iteration of the populating loop, you call `usernames.Add(..., tempArray)` which assigns `tempArray` instance to the first user key. Then the second iteration re-uses the same array and assigns it to the next user key. Since you are not initializing a new array instance for each user, you are actually associating all of your keys with the same array. The final iteration of the loop will determine the state of this array.

This should fix it:

```csharp
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    string[] tempArray = new string[5];
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
        if (j != 0) tempArray[j-1] = userInfo[i, j];
    }
    userNames.Add(userInfo[i, 0], tempArray);
}
```